# Is there a bash script to parse the output of smaps

Tags: linux, kernel, scripting

I need to parse the output of "proc/pid/smaps" on a linux system. Running a perl/python script on this system is not an option.
I was looking to see if there's a bash script to do the same.

Alternately, it would also be OK is there's a script (any script) which takes in output from /proc/pid/smaps in text format, and parses the information and dumps in human readable format :-)

Comment: It's a text file, so you can do almost anything you like with it in bash, even if its not the best choice, what exactly do you want, example input and output would be useful.

Comment: Yes, but I could not find an explanation anywhere on how to interpret the cryptic output of smaps. I find multiple entries for a process' binary, or for any of the shared libs that it uses. If it would show only one, I can interpret that as details about that process (binary) or its libs. But I dont know what multiple lines for each binary mean. Do I make sense?

Answer (score 0):

A pretty high-level explanation of the content of /proc/pid/smaps is explained here: http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc.  Search for 'smaps'.

The Linux kernel source can also be consulted, though that'll probably be more confusing unless you're familiar with the kernel.

In response to your comment, each 'section' is a Virtual Memory mapping, which could be to parts of a file, such as the executable .text section, data area of a shared library, stack, etc.

Executable part of the loader:
b7f5d000-b7f77000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2746096    /lib/ld-2.7.so

The processes' stack
bf84a000-bf85f000 rw-p bffeb000 00:00 0          [stack]